# persisting locale

Tags: locale

I want my web browser, terminal emulator, and nautilus to show in English, and I tried to set english system-wide in language support, but it didn't change except the date on the top and the gray password in login manager.
How can I fix this? And what is the cause of this? Mine is 20.04 LTS.

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"

$ locale
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

$ echo $LANG
ja_JP.UTF-8
```

Comment: Have you logged out and relogged in? Some of the locale files are only read when authenticating.

Comment: You could also try rebooting, that might help too

Comment: I've tried logging out and rebooting. The problem remains.

Comment: Well, somewhere you have set `LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8`, and you should know best where. ;) You may want to check the `~/.profile` and `~/.pam_environment` files.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks. It was .profile. I don't remember setting it but there was. I want to learn how ubuntu decides locale. Is there any resource to learn it?